# How to Retrieve HTML File in mail

Tags: html, jakarta-ee

Could any one help me out retrieving HTML file in mail?

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML should be attached to mail as attachment and your mail message should have multipart  style. ten you will be able to fetch it with regular mail API.